# Android animation bug, slides out and disapears

Tags: java, android

My animation just slides out and then it disapears? Can someonehelp me solve my problem?

at the top i declared this

```
private RelativeLayout buttonContainer;
   buttonContainer = (RelativeLayout) sidebar.getParent();
```

Here's my code of the function part:

```
      private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

   public void startTapped(View view) {
       sideBar(44, 0);
   }

   public void sideBar(final int translateX, final int translateY)
   {
       TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, translateX, 0, translateY);
       translate.setDuration(1500);
       translate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonContainer.removeView(sidebar);
            sidebar = new ImageView(Game.this);
            sidebar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
            if(out == 0)
            {
            params.leftMargin = translateX + params.leftMargin;
            params.topMargin = translateY + params.topMargin;
            params.rightMargin = 0 + params.rightMargin;
            params.bottomMargin = 0 + params.bottomMargin;
            sidebar.setLayoutParams(params);
            buttonContainer.addView(sidebar);
            out=1;
            }
            else if(out == 1)
            {
                params.leftMargin = translateX - params.leftMargin;
                params.topMargin = translateY - params.topMargin;
                params.rightMargin = 0 - params.rightMargin;
                params.bottomMargin = 0 - params.bottomMargin;
                sidebar.setLayoutParams(params);
                buttonContainer.addView(sidebar);
                out=0;
            }
        }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    switch(v.getId())
    {


        case R.id.sidebar:
            startTapped(sidebar);
        break;
    }       
}
```

It slides out like it supposed to and disappears but!, I can still tap on it, but it's just invisible.

Answer (score 0):

A ton of your code is missing here.. and you don't really describe your goal very well.. but it looks like you are way over complicating things.  Try this:

```
public void startTapped(View view) {
    if (view.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        view.startAnimation(sideBar(context.getResources()
               .getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.side_bar_width)*-1, 0));
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.startAnimation(sideBar(0, context.getResources()
               .getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.side_bar_width)*-1));
    }
}

public Animation sideBar(int start, int finish) {
    TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(start, finish, 0, 0);
    translate.setDuration(1500);
    return translate;
}
```

add a `dimens.xml` file to your `values` folder is `res`:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="side_bar_width">44dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

You will also want to set your sidebar view to `android:visibility="gone"` so that the menu isn't open when the app starts.

Comment: When i do this it will slide out to the right and instantly go back to where it was again and when i click on it again it will then pop up to that location and slide back left

Comment: Also, the reason why it's like how I had it was because, I could NOT click on it when it slide out to the right. I had to click on the original location. Can you please update your code sense I gave you a better meaing

Comment: In my code I showed above. When it slides out to the right, it will slide out and then just disappear. BUT I can still click on the disappeared box.

Comment: I assume you are creating something like a slide in menu.  so the animation comes in from off the screen and on close slides back off.  You should draw the menu in the place it will be used.  so the animation is just to give the illusion that is goes off the screen, all you are really doing is making it visible or gone.

Comment: When i use your code, it slides out and then slides right back in. but when i click again it will slide back in as if it was always out.

Comment: I also have to click it where it was in the first location. I can't click it where it slides out to.

Comment: ok, my code had a bug, just built a sample project to test it.. try the new code above

Comment: can you post your layout?  the above code works fine but I want to see  your xml to see where your menu is by default.

Comment: remove your layout_marginLeft on the side bar and I'd recommend you use dp instead of sp.. I'll add some code above to dynamically access the correct dp's from a dimens file.

Comment: How am I supposed to click on it in the first place if it's invisible? And the Margin Left part is to make it look like its off the screen. Also the start Tapped is accessed when you click on the sidebar.

Comment: The code above is for a slide-in menu that is either fully on the screen of fully off the screen with a separate view that has the attached onClick() to show and hide the view. You will need to use a margin based animation to do what you are trying to achieve.  The half and half view slide wasn't clear in your original post.